# Java Regex: What will be the regular expression for pattern like "10{1,1 %d},10{2,1 %d}"?

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

Consider following example:

```
Regex: (.\*?),(.\*)
String: 10,20
Result: Group1: 10; Group2: 20
```

Similarly,

```
Regex: ???
String: 10{1,1 %d},10{2,1 %d}
Expected result: Group1: 10{1,1 %d}; Group2: 10{2,1 %d}
```

As in second example, string contains "," many times, which result in unexpected output. In this case, How we can achieve expected result?

Comment: will there always be braces followed by a comma?  If so you can match on that pattern

Comment: No, sometimes string will be like: "10|1,1 %d|10,{2,1 %d}10", "{1,1 %d}10,10<2,1 %d>10". The string contains |{}<> characters anywhere but if "," contains in between <> or {} or || then we have to consider this as one string

Comment: Not quite sure what you're trying to do. Are you trying to separate a string by commas unless the comma is enclosed in {} or ||

Comment: I am trying to parse a text file that contains some strings like "@C10,1", "@C10,<10,1>" and mentioned above example. So what I have to do is first to match the string whether it fits in "@CXX,YYY" format, if yes then split XX and YYY by ",".  There are two things: 1. Match the string and 2. takeout the parameters XX & YYY. When I do this, I will get unexpcted results for above examples like ""{1,1 %d}10,10<2,1 %d>10"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Splitting carefully

So it sounds like you want to split the string by commas unless the commas are enclosed in a pair of matching delimiters such as "{} [] <> ||". For the moment, i am assuming that this file will be regular and not have nested markers.

So to find all these groups we want to consider a match to be any string of characters except commas, **AND** a partial match is valid if you have surrounding markers.

---

### Code

```java
String pattern = "[^,]*?({.*?}|\[.*?]|<.*?>|\|.*?\|)[^,]*?";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
```

This pattern should do it for you. It will match any string that starts without a comma, has kind of wrapper in "{} [] <> ||" and can possibly end with some text. You could even wrap `pattern` in a group and have it repeat. Like so:

```java
String pattern = "([^,]*?({.*?}|\[.*?]|<.*?>|\|.*?\|)[^,]*?)+"; // Notice the parens on the outside and the '+'
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
```

If the braces are optional also consider:

```java
String pattern = "[^,]*?({.*?}|\[.*?]|<.*?>|\|.*?\|)?[^,]*?"; // Notice the added '?'
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
```

I forget exactly what the java implementation for searching a string for multiple result is, however this works in python using the `search`, `match`, and the `finditer` methods, and the pattern will still work with java.

Comment: Your regex helped to finalize the regex. Thanks a lot Ranga